# Failed to send FCM send notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, ruby-on-rails-5, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `fcm` [gem](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm) for sending push notifications in my rails application. I can able to retrieve the firebase registration id successfully.

But sending firebase notification results in `Type Error ["registration_id"] is not a symbol or a string`, the request is not hitting the firebase. My controller code is as follows,

```
class FirebaseNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  require 'fcm'

  def send_notification
    @fcm = ENV['FCM_SERVER']
    notification = 
    { 
      "notification": 
       {
         "title": "test title",
         "message": "test body"
       }
    }
    response = @fcm.send(['firebase_registration_id'], notification)
  end
end
```

I have even tried `JSON parse`, but still could not able to solve the error. What could be the solution and also my rails version is `5.2.3` and ruby version is `2.6.3`.

Comment: Do you try? `@fcm.send('firebase_registration_id', notification)`

Comment: yes, error thrown as `undefined method for string`

Comment: Are you sure this `@fcm = ENV['FCM_SERVER']` returns an fcm object? ENV variables are string, looks like you are just using `send` method of a string. You have to instantiate a proper FCM object `fcm = FCM.new("my_server_key")`.